# World Scale for mobile in Unity?

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine, scale

I'm experimenting with android apps in the unity engine, but I'm having problems where the gameobjects in the world don't scale with the device. Unity has all sorts of tutorials for UI scaling, and my UI scales fine, but I don't see any Unity documentation for anything like this.

For context the game is a very simple puzzle type game where you throw a ball by tapping on the screen, the ball then bounces off objects to get to a goal.

Sorry about my poor drawing skills, but I think it gives to best example of what's happening.

I designed my device scale for a Galaxy Note 10, and it looks fine:

[image]

But when I play the game on a smaller/older device, you can't see what happening in game because everything is too big:

[image]

And on an even larger device like a tablet, things are way to small:

[image]

How do I get my world to scale for different resolutions and aspect ratios, but and the same distance between objects so that I if the ball it launched in the same direction on all devices it will bounce off objects in the same places and hit or miss the target in the same way on all devices?

Comment: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/camera/camera-fit-screen-handler-57439

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the reviews for the asset that someone commented you will find this

> In Unity 2018.2 and above, you can now tick the "physical camera" box on any camera, and set the gate fit to "overscan". Then, just make sure that the sensor size is 16:9, or whatever your "reference aspect ratio" is. You can also experiment with other gate fits depending on your needs.

Since you already tried overscan and it didn't appear to work I will look at other options. After reading the entire unity manual on physical cameras, change the gatfit to none. This will stretch the image to fill the screen but your scene fits most devices so don't worry about stretching.

Comment: For your first option, can you explain better how I would do that? What objects I would need to put it on? etc.

For the feature added in Unity 2018.2, I tried that and it made it so you could see everything on all devices, but it was also really small on all devices

Comment: I would go with the second option so press the play button on your game and near the top left corner of the game test window you should see a resolution, write it down. Go to https://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/aspect_ratio/ and type in the screen height in h1 and the screen width in w1. This should give you an aspect ratio to use.

Comment: Using those numbers (53 : 113) my scene is extremely small. I will note though that I don't have a "gate fit" option so I can't switch it to "overscan". https://imgur.com/a/tnx82tC

Comment: The comment says that you need 2018.2 and above do you have that?

Comment: I'm running 2018.4 LTS, I would't even have a toggle for the physical camera without it.

Comment: In the unity docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PhysicalCameras.html   I believe the problem is that you need your version to be above unity 2019.1

Comment: I will spend the next few days upgrading to 2019.2, however the documentation I see says otherwise, https://imgur.com/a/733RvSX

Comment: After Updating to 2019.2, setting "Gate Fit" to "overscan", and setting the sensor size to 54 by 113 it looks fine in 16:9 but gets cut off just like the second image in my original post. Do all the variables in my camera component look correct? https://imgur.com/a/r7npY7t

Comment: Try tweaking the settings until it scales correctly.

Comment: What kind of things would you recommend tweaking?

Comment: After reading the entire unity manual on physical cameras change the gatfit to none. This will stretch the image to fill the screen but your scene fits most devices so don't worry about stretching.

Comment: I updated my answer to fit my comment above, If my answer did work please mark it as the right answer.

Comment: Thank your for your time, It appears stretching the display won't work either though as it causes things to become warped to the point where things become hard to discern.

Comment: I think the only option left is to try to re-design everything for Unity's UI but there probably are other people that could help you with this so try posting your question on the Unity forums.